# Closed form to exponential equation?

Tags: number-theory, exponential-function, roots, quadratics, problem-solving

I have an equation: $6 \cdot 4^x - 13 \cdot 6^x + 69^x = 0$

Is there an analytical way to solve for $x$ or is this something where numerical methods are the only feasible method? Taking logs of both sides is not enough to separate the terms.

Comment: Perhaps it should be $6\cdot 9^x$?

Comment: this would make more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$6 \cdot 4^x - 13 \cdot 6^x + 6\cdot 9^x = 0 /:4^x$$
then $$ 6t^2-13t+6=0$$ where $t=(3/2)^x$ ...

Comment: also $5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2$